# JWT token is not validated therefore it returns 401 unauthorized every time

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, jwt

I have a webapp that uses JWT tokens to authenticate. I created this webapp using `dotnetcore 2.0` and `Angular2 +`.

I'm able to create tokens. I can retrieve the data with anonymous mode. The problem is I can't retrieve the database values when I authorize the controller. The controller code is :

```
namespace AuthDemo.Controllers
{
 [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
 //[Authorize]
 [Route("api/[Controller]")]

 public class ProductsController : Controller
 {
    private readonly IProductRepository repository;
    public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository)
    {
        this.repository = repository;

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Product> Get()
    {
        return repository.GetAllProducts();
    }

 }
}
```

The code snippet that I use inside `startup.cs` is below:

```
        services.AddIdentity<AppUser, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        }).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication().AddCookie().AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
            {
                ValidIssuer = configuration["Tokens: Issuer"],
                ValidAudience = configuration["Tokens: Audience"],
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Tokens:Key"]))
            };
        });
```

I also added `app.UseAuthentication();` inside the `configure app` method before `app.useMvc()`.

Lastly, my JWT configuration is located in `appsettings.json` file and it is as below:

```
  "Tokens": {
     "Key": "hdhfdhskfhskdfhskdfsfSJLKSFJSDJFDSFKDSFKDSLKkd;dkflksdlf",
     "Issuer": "localhost", 
     "Audience": "http://localhost:5000/"
  }
```

Again, I am still getting **401 Unauthorized**.

Comment: How are you creating the jwt tokeens? Are you using IdentityServer or OpenIddict/ASOS? Are the values in your ValidIssuer and ValidAudience correct? try removing the space in the configuration indexer, i.e. `configuration["Tokens: Issuer"]`=> `configuration["Tokens:Issuer"]`

Comment: I am an idiot! Removing spaces inside `startup.cs` has solved the issue! @Tseng Please post your comment as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if the values in `ValidIssue` and `ValidAudience` are correct.

Try removing the space in the configuration indexer, i.e. `configuration["Tokens: Issuer"]` should be `configuration["Tokens:Issuer"]`.